# How to deep filter in array with objects in JS

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array and want to get just object **{ id: 4, name: 'name4' },**

```
const example = [
    {
      id: '1234',
      desc: 'sample1',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'name1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' }
       ]
      },    
    {
        id: '3456',
        desc: 'sample2',
      items: [
         { id: 4, name: 'name4' },
         { id: 5, name: 'testItem5' }
       ]
    },
```

I try in this way.

```
const name = 'name4';
example.forEach((item) => item.items.find((i) => i.name === name));
```

But get undefined.

Comment: This will help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using [**flatMap()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to do it

```js
const example = [
    {
      id: '1234',
      desc: 'sample1',
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'name1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' }
       ]
      },    
    {
        id: '3456',
        desc: 'sample2',
        items: [
         { id: 4, name: 'name4' },
         { id: 5, name: 'testItem5' }
       ]
    }]
    
const name = 'name4';
let result = example.flatMap(e => e.items).filter(d => d.name == name)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wow. I never bothered to read what `.flatMap` does and now I regret my life choices. (It's been available since 2015). What a useful method this is.

Answer (score 2):

this way...?

```js
const example = 
  [ { id   : '1234'
    , desc : 'sample1'
    , items: 
      [ { id: 1, name: 'name1'     } 
      , { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' } 
    ] } 
  , { id   : '3456'
    , desc : 'sample2'
    , items: 
      [ { id: 4, name: 'name4'     } 
      , { id: 5, name: 'testItem5' } 
  ] } ]; 

const rechName = (s,arr) => 
  arr.find( x =>         // find the first parent object
    x.items.some( y =>  // containing the search
     y.name === s )
   )?.items                       // if one
     .find( z => z.name === s ); // find it in!

console.log( rechName('name4', example) ) // -> { id: 4, name: 'name4' }
console.log( rechName('abc', example) )  // -> undefined
```

Comment: I like this better, because this avoids collecting all the items into one massive array.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` doesn't do what you think it does. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.
>
> ...
>
> Return value
> `undefined`.

So if you want to use `forEach` you need to save the value:

```js
const example = 
  [ { id   : '1234'
    , desc : 'sample1'
    , items: 
      [ { id: 1, name: 'name1'     } 
      , { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' } 
    ] } 
  , { id   : '3456'
    , desc : 'sample2'
    , items: 
      [ { id: 4, name: 'name4'     } 
      , { id: 5, name: 'testItem5' } 
  ] } ] 
  
const results = []; // Store matches here

const name = 'name4';
example.forEach((item) => {
  const res = item.items.find((i) => i.name === name);
  if (res !== undefined) {
    results.push(res);
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

IMHO I would suggest a more functional approach using `flatMap` and `filter` instead of `forEach`.

Lastly, note that in my above snippet, I'm storing the results in an array as it's not entirely clear to me that you won't have multiple matches per your example. But if you're sure that you will only ever have one result then a simple for loop works better, especially if you have a large array of items:

```js
let result = null;
for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  const res = example[i].items.find((j) => j.name === name);
  if (res !== undefined) {
    result = res;
    break; // No need to iterate further
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive search function. Here's a detailed example:

```js
// Applies the function recursively from the top of the data tree ("depth-first")
const
  data = getData(),
  id = 4,
  result = findById(data, id);
console.log(result ?? `No item with id ${id} found`);

// Defines the function
function findById(haystack, needleId){
  let needle = null; // Defaults to null if no match at or below this level

  // Iterates through all the items at this level
  for(const item of haystack){
    if(item.id == needleId){
      // Qapla': Quits early, passes honorable item up to previous level
      needle = item;
      return needle;
    }
    else {
      // Checks children, grandchildren, etc, before continuing iteration
      const nextHaystack = item.items;
      if(nextHaystack?.length){
        needle = findById(nextHaystack, needleId); // Recursive call
      }
    }
    // Done searching children, continues to next iteration at this level
  }
  // Done searching this level, returns result up to previous level
  return needle;
}

// Gets the initial data
function getData(){
  return [
    {
      id: '1234',
      desc: 'sample1',
      items: [ { id: 1, name: 'name1' }, { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' } ]
    },
    {
      id: '3456',
      desc: 'sample2',
      items: [ { id: 4, name: 'name4' }, { id: 5, name: 'testItem5' } ]
    }
  ];
}
```